# To develop in Android is it an absolute necessity to use Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

Do I need to use Eclipse IDE in order to develop in Android ? Most of the user guides insist on Eclipse !

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't. See [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/index.html) for instructions on how to develop, both with and without eclipse.

[Managing Projects from the Command Line](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html) and [Building and Running from the Command Line](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-cmdline.html), for example, shows how to manage and build a project (without Eclipse), respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is very good IDE for android application development. Otherwise there are other IDE's like:

```
Netbeans, JetBrains as mentioned by DAC
```

Plus you have got:

- [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/google_android.html)

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't; however, I don't see why you'd want to do otherwise. It greatly simplifies things when using Google's own SDK and Eclipse plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be somewhat futile to develop for Android without an IDE if you plan on using the emulator, debugging and anything else that is useful for Android development; however, most of the other large Java IDE's support android:

- [NetBeans](http://wiki.netbeans.org/IntroAndroidDevNetBeans)
- [JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/google_android.html)

Comment: You'd be amazed how far you can get without an IDE. You can even write multiple books and a few thousand StackOverflow answers on Android without using an IDE. :-)

Comment: I appreciate it can be done! But this for this particular target, in my opinion, it seems a little pointless to not use an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not. You could even use nicer languages like scala... (take with a pinch of salt)